# How to Make a Class Function Change Object Image (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, function, class, action

I'm new to both Stack Overflow and VB.NET (Coming from C)  so please bear with me on this one :)
I'm making a hangman game as an assignment for my Programming Class, and I've created a Public Class Character, with a Public Function Death() As Action
The player will be able to choose from a variety of characters, each one with a different death animation, so I'd like to make Death() change the character image over and over in a stop-motion style, for example

```
Death(){
    pictureboxchar.image(1.png)
    pictureboxchar.image(2.png)
    pictureboxchar.image(3.png)
    pictureboxchar.image(4.png)
}
```

But I'm not quite sure as to what I should refer to instead of "pictureboxchar". Maybe I should refer to the class name Character itself?
I'd like to accomplish this, as creating a custom class for the character will give me extra credits.

```
Public Class Character
    Public Function Death() As Action

    End Function
End Class
```

This is what I have so far 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve animation, you'll need to use a timer. Your Character class could look like this. The 4 PNG files will need to be in the application's startup directory. Play around with the timer's Interval property to get the desired animation speed. Its value is in milliseconds so when set to 500, the timer's tick event will fire every half second.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Character

    Private WithEvents myTimer As New Timer
    Private iCounter As Int32
    Private iNumberImages As Int32 = 4 'images must be numbered "1.png", "2.png" etc in the order of animation
    Private iAnimationSpeed As Int32 = 500 'set to lower value for faster animation
    Private myPictureBox As PictureBox
    Private sPictureFileDirectory As String = Application.StartupPath 'the directory where the image files are located

    Public Sub New(ByVal pictureboxchar As PictureBox)
        myPictureBox = pictureboxchar
        myTimer.Interval = iAnimationSpeed
        myTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub myTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myTimer.Tick
        iCounter += 1 'increment the counter to display the next image in the sequence
        If iCounter > iNumberImages Then iCounter = 1 'reset the counter to 1 when the maximum number of images is exceeded
        Dim sFilePath As String = sPictureFileDirectory & "\" & iCounter.ToString & ".png"
        If File.Exists(sFilePath) = True Then myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(sFilePath)
    End Sub

End Class
```

From your form, create an instance of the Character class with form level scope and pass the picture box to the constructor in the form's load event handler:

```
Private myCharacter As Character

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myCharacter = New Character(pictureboxchar)
End Sub
```